# Navbar Hamburger not working, and Navbar drop down inactive?

Tags: html, css

So I am quite new to Bootstrap and followed a tutorial, my Bootstrap JS links are before the CSS links however when I click on the hamburger menu upon inspetion, neither the menu or the drop down icon will work?

What is wrong here?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class=" sr-only"> Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class=" icon-bar"> </span>
        <span class=" icon-bar"> </span>
        <span class=" icon-bar"> </span>

      </button>
      <a class=" navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap Practice</a>
    </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"> <a href="#"> Home</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#about"> About </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#"> Blog</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#"> Contact Us</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Themes <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Dashboard</li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Admin 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Admin 2</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is jQuery added too? Show us the links to css, js and jquery.

Comment: Sure thing: 
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>